# How can I mark duplicate values in a column based on a second value in a different column in Excel 2007?

Tags: excel, duplicates, excel-2007, vba

I have been trying to mark duplicates in the same excel column based on a criteria in a different column, and I would love to have some help.  In reference to the example below, I would like to highlight all the rows that is a duplicate value of another row red, and put a Y in a third column ("Delete" in the example below).  When the value in the Name column is a duplicate of another, disregarding case sensitivity, I would like to mark all but one value based on a hierarchy in the Status column, i.e Excellent, Good, and Bad.

[image]

Only one of each unique value can be left unmarked, and if two share the same status with no duplicate value of a higher status then either one can be marked (the one further down the list if thats easier to specify).

I have been looking around the site and have found lots of similar entries on deleting duplicates but nothing quite the same.  I need to highlight and not delete the duplicate rows and I have not been able to find anything that will let me sort based on a heirarchy in a second column.  I only need to execute the command once as oppose to on a recurrence so the time it takes is not a concern to me.  Any help you guys can throw my way would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: no need for VBA. Adding answer below.

Comment: Data >> Sort >> Order > Custom list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the sheet and steps below solves your issue.

1. Status_order Formula: Range("E2") =VLOOKUP(D2,$I$2:$J$4,2,FALSE)
2. Sort A1:E15 by Name, Then by Status_Order Smallest to Largest
3. Delete Formula =IF(A2=A3,"Delete","")
4. Fill All Formulas Down
5. Add Conditional Formatting on all columns to be Red if Column C = "Delete"

[image]

Comment: Thank you so very much! this solved my problem much easier than I had anticipated.

Comment: Awesome! So others can share this benefit more easily, please mark the response as answered, by clicking the check box in the upper-left corner of the answer post.

Comment: Would you also happen to be able to think of a way to mark the rows differently (such as "Pending Review" instead of delete) if you have more than 1 of the highest Status Order?  I have been trying by concatenating the Name and Status_order columns into 1 field and checking it with the fields both above and below.  Unfortunately I have not had much luck with the logic after that.

Comment: Change Formula in C2 to this `=IF(AND(A2=A3,D2=D3),"Pending Review",IF(A2=A3,"Delete",""))` and drag down.